# how to setarch for each bash session

Tags: linux, shell, session

I am using bash as my default shell. I don't have root access. But I would like to customize my bash by setarch. So the question is how to do this automatically?

Currently, I have to manually run "setarch ... /bin/bash" when I want to use thecustomized bash. Is there a way that this setarch is always automatically done for all my bash sessions?

Answer (score 1):

try to change `~/.bashrc` or change the files set the arch on the `/etc/rc.d` directory.

check it out:

[An introduction to services, runlevels, and rc.d scripts](http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts)